# What is the CTRL+x+e equivalent for MacOS's Terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, command-line

In Ubuntu's (and other Linux systems) terminal, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, which opens an editor to allow you to edit your command at leisure, with multiline support, and once you save and exit, it would return to terminal with the full command ready to execute.

I've tried the same combination in Terminal (both with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>) and it didn't do anything.

Googling the combination + macOS just gave me random tutorials about useful keyboard shortcuts in terminal and in macOS in general.

---

Does anyone know of the equivalent key combination for the MacOS Terminal? Does it even exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Control+X+E works on the macOS Terminal. Generally <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is not substituted for <kbd>Cmd</kbd> in terminal commands.

Comment: Equivalent in vi-mode: press letter `v`

Comment: Yes but note this is not a property of terminal but if the shell you are using so default is bash and it works but not with other shells

Comment: @Mark Seems to work with zsh as well at the very least.

Comment: Try tcsh (and xonsh is a bit buggy ie it should work but does not)

Comment: Doesn't work for me in zsh, even after turning on `set -o emacs` and `autoload edit-command-line zle -N edit-command-line bindkey '^Xe' edit-command-line`. Neither does esc-V with `set -o vi`. I must've broken something.

Comment: @Noumenon just checked and this still works for me (on zsh on mac)